# Show 'Save as' dialog box while downloading file from an Iframe through PHP

Tags: php, jquery, cross-domain, download

I know similar type of questions have been asked before, but I believe this one has some variance.

My web page has an `Iframe`. This iframe loads the page from some other domain (cross domain scripting is in action). Now when I click a button in this iframe, it makes an `AJAX` request through `jQuery` and creates a text file on the `PHP` server. Now I want that a normal 'Save as' dialog box should appear so that I user can download that file from the server.

I have tried all the `Content-Disposition` and `header()` function in PHP side but the 'Save as' dialog **does not** appear although the file is created successfully on the server. I think, the problem is that I want to trigger the file download from the iframe which is loading  content from some other domain.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Instead of `AJAX` use `Iframe` technique. Following `jQuery` code should be written in the iframe. It triggers the download through iframe instead of making an `AJAX` request to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#download').click(function(){
        var ifr = $('<iframe id="secretIFrame" src="" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>');
        $('body').append(ifr);
        var iframeURL = 'http://you_domain.com/download.php?str='+encodeURIComponent(data_to_be_posted);
        ifr.attr('src', iframeURL);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is the code for `download.php`:

```
<?php
$str = html_entity_decode($_REQUEST['str']);

$file_name = 'export_data.txt';

header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
header("Content-length:".(string)(filesize($str)));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/txt');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
echo $str;
exit;
?>
```