# Content-Disposition:attachment not triggering download dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express, content-disposition

I've encountered some unexpected behavior when trying to create a file download functionality on my NodeJS server.
I have a REST (express) API that calls for some export data function, which creates a CSV file on the server and uses `res.download('path/to/file')` to trigger the download.
Response headers include

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="indicators.csv"
Content-Length:30125
Content-Type:text/csv; charset=UTF-8
```

so everything seems to be in order.

The thing is, I get the response from the server as plain text. The response has all the data the CSV file contains, but does not trigger the browser's file download dialog like I intended.
I tried both on Chrome and FF. The problem persists in both.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I managed to make it work by creating a dummy form, and using its submit action to make my AJAX call. But it's an ugly hack, and I'm still looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Headers are not the issue. The issue is that you are querying the download url via an `ajax` call, which will not invoke the browser download dialog. Your options boil down to the following:

1. Use a form that is submitted to your download url. Instead of having a visible form a user has to interact with, create a form with `JavaScript` and submit it programmatically by calling `form.submit` - [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)
2. Point `window.location` to the download url. You can do this in the current window - [download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request/20830337#20830337) , or in a new one - [res.download() not working in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case/20177012#20177012)

Comment: As you can see in my question, option 1 is what I ended up using. But I must admit that option 2 might be a more elegant solution in my case.

Comment: how do these do on Safari? I've found both are treated as pop-ups and effectively hidden from the user on safari

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a different content-type, so that won't be open as a text file on the browser:

```
Content-Type:application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8
```

Another alternative could be to use application/octet-stream as mime-type to define it as a downloadable file without a better description.

```
Content-Type:application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The question looks similar to this one

[Show 'Save as' dialog box while downloading file from an Iframe through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596024/show-save-as-dialog-box-while-downloading-file-from-an-iframe-through-php)

The basic idea is the second option that Roman described above, but this one's using an iframe to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Roman Pletnev, I recommend to wrap up the API response into a made up new document as follows (Vue/csv response):

```
    API.get(apiName, path, myInit)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log(response)
            // Wrap this response into a temporary page that will trigger the download
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'text/csv' })
            const blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            const tempLink = document.createElement('a')
            tempLink.style.display = 'none'
            tempLink.href = blobURL
            tempLink.download = 'filename.csv'
            tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
            document.body.appendChild(tempLink)
            tempLink.click()
            document.body.removeChild(tempLink)
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            console.log(error.response);
        });
```