# Save As Dialog in Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs6-modern

I want to ask if there is a "**Save As**" dialog in Ext Js Modern? So I can save an Object from a web Page into a local file.

Comment: You couldn't spend 5s of your time typing "extjs dialog" into google? https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Dialog.html. Your other question has also been answered in multiple places already

Comment: This is not what I need!! I am enough good in Sencha and this dialog is not as what described in the question!!!!
I don't think that it is implemented in the Ext Js. but may be someone else has done that...

Comment: What do you need in the Save As? Dialog can have text and buttons, or you can have something with less config with e.g. https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.5.1/classic/Ext.MessageBox.html. You have to of course do the saving logic yourself.

Comment: I emailed Sencha and they have told that they do not have a save as component.  They gave me other solution which depends on the browser itself. it is also not what I am looking for. therefore I will try to find a better solution and I will post it when it is ready

Comment: It's quite widely supported to create a Blob url and the "download" attribute on anchor tags, I would try them in combination. Or File API but I think that would have less support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution depends on the Portlet Concept:

1. in  ViewController you fire an event ex "downloadFile"
2. in Main Controller you catch the event and execute a function "downloadFile" and call a function in let it the same name
3. AjaxController (Ext.app.Controller) you call the function doStandardSubmit

   location.href = this.url + '&operation=download&param1=' + param1val;
4. in the Backend of the portlet (Java) you write the endPOint method :

   @EndpointMethod(encode = false)
   public void download(DataAccessor dataAccessor, AuthenticationGenerationConfiguration configuration,
   @RequestKey String param1, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException {

   OutputStream outputStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();
   try {

   ```
               // Adjusting content type
               response.setContentType("text/plain");
               response.setProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FILENAME + "\"");
                   outputStream.flush();
           } finally {
               outputStream.close();
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Does this work to trigger a download on the browser? I found even with content-disposition etc on my project I still had to do some extra stuff to trigger one (would be cool if it did then I can re-examine my project)

Comment: no this will trigger the operating system to show the save as dialog. its safe because it does not depend on the browser. I must test it more to enhance it

Comment: Yes but in a normal ajax call it won't trigger a download - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318930/414062

Comment: the AJAx call will trigger the download function which is written in the portlet. and it will in turn trigger the download.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution (Depends on the Web Browser and is not supported by all browsers!) is using Mozilla API (File and BLOB) like in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob