# HTTP Response with Content-Disposition doesn't trigger download

Tags: javascript, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, msw

I use [msw](https://mswjs.io/) to mock backend responses for automated FE tests.

I wanted to create an Export Functionality for user-created data. I am `POST`ing a Request to the desired route, and want to return a response with a .csv ; .pdf ; .xls file which should be downloaded automatically.

I've been searching for appropriate ways to do that and came across the `Content-Disposition` Response Header.

**Sadly the response doesn't trigger a save dialoge, nor start a download**, but I can't find the mistake.

---

> **EDIT:** After having a few conversations and the somewhat unique circumstances, I settled for creating a ObjectURL for the Blob-Data
> generated, and force a download with the `window.open()` call.
>
> I changed the expected Response in my Handlers and added a
> corresponding call in my FE.
>
> **handlers.js**
>
> ```
> rest.post('/mock/things/:thingId/export', async (req, res, ctx) => {
>   const docType = req.headers.get('Content-type');
>   const startDate = req.url.searchParams.get('startDate');
>   const endDate = req.url.searchParams.get('endDate');
>   const selected = req.body;
>
>   const resDataString = 'testName,testLastName,\r\nDaniel,Schaller';
>   const blob = new Blob([resDataString], { type: docType });
>   const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
>
>   return res(
>     ctx.status(200),
>     ctx.set({
>       'content-type': `${docType}`,
>       'Content-length': buffer.byteLength.toString(),
>     }),
>     ctx.body(buffer),
>     ctx.delay(),
>   );
> }),
> ```
>
> **store-module.js**
>
> ```
> async exportThings(ctx, exportData) {
>   const {
>     docType, startDate, endDate, selected,
>   } = exportData;
>
>   const res = await services.exportThingsForStuff(ctx.state.id, docType, startDate, endDate, selected);
>
>   if (res.data !== undefined) {
>     const dataBLOB = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers['content-type'] });
>     window.open(URL.createObjectURL(dataBLOB));
>   }
> },
> ```

---

Let me show you the workflow:

**some-component.vue**

```
async submitExport() {
  const exportDataFilters = {
    docType: this.docType,
    startDate: this.startDate,
    endDate: this.endDate,
    selected: this.selected,
  };

  const response = await this.$store.dispatch('exportThings', exportDataFilters);
  console.log(response);
},
```

---

**store-module.js**

```
async exportThings(ctx, exportData) {
  const {
    docType, startDate, endDate, selected,
  } = exportData;

  return services.exportThingsForStuff(ctx.state.id, docType, startDate, endDate, selected);
},
```

---

**services.js**

```
export const exportThingsForStuff = async (thingsId, docType, startDate, endDate, pl) => axios.post(`/mock/things/${thingsId}/export`, pl, {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': docType,
  },
  params: {
    startDate,
    endDate,
  },
```

---

**And Finally the MSW Response function from handlers.js**

```
rest.post('/mock/things/thingId/export', (req, res, ctx) => {
  // Vars will be in use to mimic filter behavior, as soon as the download problem is solved
  const docType = req.headers.get('Content-type');
  const startDate = req.url.searchParams.get('startDate');
  const endDate = req.url.searchParams.get('endDate');
  const selected = req.body;


  
// Creating a test string and blobbing it.
const resDataString = 'testName,testLastName,\r\nJoe,Moe';
const blob = new Blob([resDataString], { type: 'text/csv' });

return res(
  ctx.status(200),
  ctx.set({
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="things_export.csv"',
    'Content-Length': blob.size.toString(),
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
  }),
  ctx.body(blob),
  ctx.delay(),
);
```

}),

I can't find the problem with it, since the response looks like expected:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/mock/things/101/export?startDate=&endDate=
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

RESPONSE HEADERS
content-disposition: attachment; filename="things_export.csv"
content-length: 37
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: text/csv
x-powered-by: msw
```

Comment: Can you try sending text in `ctx.body` instead of a Blob?

Comment: @kettanaito I tried pretty much everything. HTML, plain Text, stringified HTML and blobs. Sadly the outcome doesn't change. I get the response with the proper data in each case, yet the download doesn't trigger as expected.

Comment: `content-transfer-encoding` is a MIME header, not an http one. To force a download your content-type header value should be `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Please, could you trying providing [`responseType: 'blob'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) when [configuring](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) the axios `POST` in the `exportThingsForStuff` method: `export const exportThingsForStuff = async (thingsId, docType, startDate, endDate, pl) => axios.post(`/mock/things/${thingsId}/export`, pl, {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': docType,
  },
  params: {
    startDate,
    endDate,
  },
  responseType: 'blob'`. Please, could you try?

Comment: Please, consider review [this related so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios) as well, I think it can be of help

Comment: @miknik Does not work. And in combination with `Content-Disposition: attachment` the application/octet-stream should not be necessary. Since I know the given Data-Type of my response data, application/octet-stream is not the right choice imo.

Comment: @jccampanero The response-type didn't change the behaviour, but thanks for the heads up. I looked into the linked question, but I really don't want to programatically append and click a link for the sole purpose of downloading a file.

Comment: You are welcome @D.Schaller. I am very sorry to see that the advice was not helpful.

Comment: @D.Schaller I honestly have never worked with that mocking library, but have you tested [this](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/binary-response-type) approach for returning the binary information?

Comment: @jccampanero Yes I did. No it does not work. I tested all I can think of (including the approaches from documentations and various SO posts).

Comment: I see @D.Schaller. I think the main issue is dealing with the download in the context of the test; I mean, I think the anchor solution proposed in the related SO question can be a good approach for instance if running the application in the browser. If you have access to the response blob in your code, a similar but different approach I followed sometimes is the following: `const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); window.open(blobUrl);`, being `blob` the returned blob in your response. The problem is that the user experience is worse because you lost the ability of naming your file

Comment: @jccampanero Tried using this method, it might actually work. naming the file is not necessarily needed in my use case. Testing it I stumbled across a somewhat strange behaviour. The response seems to always be converted to a string, hence losing whatever I did with it before. I'm sending a blob, but the response data is neither binary, nor a blob, but the fully evaluated data as a string. I'm wondering if that is the reason why nothing really works regarding 'Content-Disposition'. Maybe I have to switch the Mocking Library...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you are consuming the response from that link your Javascript application, right? In that case browser won't do open download dialog.
You should redirect user to a link to trigger download dialog. But you want to use a POST method, than fill in a form and submit it programmatically instead of calling `axios.post`

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to provide an answer. I settled for the option of creating an ObjectURL and opening it with `window.open(ObjectURL)` since initial naming of the file isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737883/content-dispositionattachment-not-triggering-download-dialog)

I guess it's a browser feature...

I don't like download it with `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` too.
seems I have to use the old school HTML form element or HTTP get

thanks for the precise description though.
I have the same issue and your question direct me to the related answer above, which really helps!